# Memory sections of a process

Tags: process

According to the textbook "operating systems concepts 9th ". The memory of a process is divided into different sections. One of the sections is the data section. The book states that :

> Informally, as mentioned earlier, a process is a program in execution.
> A process is more than the program code, which is sometimes known as
> the text section. It also includes the current activity, as
> represented by the value of the program counter and the contents of
> the processor’s registers.

What is the exact meaning of "current activity" ? Does this means that the program counter of the process and the contents of the processor's registers are stored in the text section ?

Comment: @Paul_Pedant thanks alot . But where exactly we save the content of the cpu registers and the program counter when a context switch happens ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The executable code (text section) is read-only, so it cannot have any of the variable values of the "current activity" (process) stored in it.

The statement means the process state includes program counter and registers; while the process is active, these aren't in memory, they're "in" the CPU. They are saved to memory when the process is not active.

The program as compiled on Linux is stored in a binary format called [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format). There are utilities which report on the contents; run `nm -n -g` or `readelf -l` on a binary to get a feel for this.

The program contents are grouped according to their protection and initialisation requirements, so the kernel can enforce read-only pages and block initialisations when it loads them. You'll find a description of the in-memory layout in [Wikipedia's "Data segment" article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment); it omits rodata (read-only data) which is historically held in text along with the code in Unix.

Storing the "current activity" is dependent on the CPU architecture. Linux has pre-emptive scheduling. The CPU can be running a process, receive an interrupt, and in the very next cycle be running something else. The CPU itself pushes the minimal amount of context onto a stack during an interrupt: the program counter, the processor flags, and an error code. Then it jumps to an address in the kernel that has been pre-configured in an Interrupt Descriptor Table.

The kernel then has to store any remaining CPU registers and other context, because it will need to reconstruct the exact state of the interrupted process when it finally gets restarted using a Return From Interrupt instruction. You can read more on [interrupt handling in Linux here](https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/refs/heads/master/lectures/interrupts.html).